# How to execute query in string mode in pl/sql?

Tags: sql, database, plsql

I m trying to execute the procedure but it is showing the errror of missing expression while executing this line  ***execute immediate sqlQuery into test;***
My query returns 6 columns which i need to store into the variables , please help to execute this query.

```
procedure getAttributeOptions(subID number, compID number,docNumber varchar2,transType varchar2 ,rowNum varchar2 ,
          Attribute1 out varchar2,Attribute2 out varchar2,Attribute3 out varchar2,Attribute4 out varchar2,
          Attribute5 out varchar2, Attribute6 out varchar2) is
sqlQuery varchar2(4000);
storageColumns varchar2(4000);
colName varchar2(1000);
tableName varchar2(1000);
primaryKey varchar2(1000);
test varchar2(4000);

begin
 colName:=' ATTRIBUTE_OPTION_1,ATTRIBUTE_OPTION_2,ATTRIBUTE_OPTION_3,ATTRIBUTE_OPTION_4,ATTRIBUTE_OPTION_5,ATTRIBUTE_OPTION_6 ';
 storageColumns:=' Attribute1,Attribute2,Attribute3,Attribute4,Attribute5,Attribute6 ';

  if transType = TY_ISSUE then
    tableName:='preq_master_detail';
    primaryKey:='req_number';
  elsif transType=TY_TRANSFER then 
     tableName:='pinv_transfer_detail'; 
     primaryKey:='transfer_id';
  elsif transType=TY_RECEIVE then 
    tableName:='ppo_master_detail';
    primaryKey:='po_number';
  elsif transType=TY_MANUAL then 
    tableName:='part_manual_adjustment';
    primaryKey:='adjustment_id';
    end if;
  
  dbms_output.put_line(tableName);
  
  if tableName is not null then
   begin
    sqlQuery:='select ' || colName || 'into ' || storageColumns || 'from ' || tableName ;
    sqlQuery:=sqlQuery  || ' where subscriber_id=' || subID; 
    sqlQuery:=sqlQuery  || ' and company_id=' || compID;
    sqlQuery:=sqlQuery  || ' and ' || primaryKey ||'='|| '''' || docNumber || '''' || ' and row_number ='||rowNum;
    
    dbms_output.put_line(sqlQuery); 
    execute immediate sqlQuery into test;--issue in this line 
    
     dbms_output.put_line(Attribute1); 
     dbms_output.put_line(Attribute2); 
     dbms_output.put_line(Attribute3); 
     dbms_output.put_line(Attribute4); 
     dbms_output.put_line(Attribute5); 
     dbms_output.put_line(Attribute6); 
    
    exception when NO_DATA_FOUND then return ;
   end; 
  end if;
  end;
```

Comment: If you select 6 columns you need to select into 6 variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are placing the list of variables for your INTO clause inside the SQL, rather than outside in PL/SQL.  You need to use put the INTO clause outside. Hopefully you can hard-code that clause:

```
sqlQuery:='select ' || colName || 'from ' || tableName ;
. . .
execute immediate sqlQuery into Attribute1,Attribute2,Attribute3,Attribute4,Attribute5,Attribute6;
```

While you are at it, you should use bind variables for your WHERE clause:

```
. . .
 sqlQuery:=sqlQuery  || ' where subscriber_id=:subid';
 sqlQuery:=sqlQuery  || ' and company_id=:compID';
 sqlQuery:=sqlQuery  || ' and ' || primaryKey ||'= :docno'|| ' and row_number =:rowNum';

execute immediate sqlQuery 
  INTO Attribute1,Attribute2,Attribute3,Attribute4,Attribute5,Attribute6 
 USING subid,compid,docNumber,rowNum;
```

That will make your DBA happy.